# after each successful response, request again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

From my html page, the ajax request response will works like a loop. That mean's when a successful response come back, again a request will go. I did like the following but that works for only 2 consecutive request-response and I also can understand why.

```
 $.get("chat1", function(data, status){
    $("#data").html(data);
    $.get("chat1", function(data, status){
        $("#data").html(data);
    });     
});
```

But, i want to make it automatic. How can i do this? FYI: i am trying to implement long polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.get(this)` to make the same request again in the success callback function.